# Granularity of BloC usage in flutter with nested data

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc

What is best practice of bloc usage with nested data, when I have a list view, a detail view of the selected record and maybe a detail view of a subrecord?

Let's say I have an app, showing some reports.

**Option A)**
One bloc for each view (e.g. AllReportsBloc, ReportsDetailBloc, ContactDetailBloc)

[image of architecture option a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1csi.jpg)

**Option B)**
One single bloc for all three views (e.g. ReportsBloc)

[image of architecture option b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI9ef.jpg)

I've tried both of them but neither option a nor option b seems to be a solid solution

**The problem with Option A)**
With three different bloc's I also have three different states of the same data source. If I change data of a single record for example, I'll handle this over ReportsDetailBloc. So the state of ReportsDetailBloc will change. But the same record is also represented in the state of AllRecordsBloc, but here it's still the old data. That's needs me to think about bloc-to-bloc communication, but I don't want to [connect bloc through presentation](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=connecting-blocs-through-presentation) as described in the official bloc docs. Connecting blocks via the presentation layer does not seem to be consistent with the idea of reactive programming, in my opinion. And it's hard to maintain as I have to know where I placed this connections in the whole ui.

**The problem with Option B)**
One single bloc may become huge and complex. And it's hard to trigger the ui on a granular level. So I end up in defining tons of status definitions (like allReportsLoading, singleReportLoading, singleContactLoading, allReportsLoadingError, singleReportLoadingError, ...) to precisely target state changes in the ui.

Does anyone has an advice for me? Is there an Option C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option A is the ideal answer.

Since all of the blocs depends on the same repository, you can create a stream or a variable that can hold the updated Reports inside the repository.

Here's an example from `bloc`'s [Todos app](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial?id=todosrepository).

Inside your `blocs, create an event that can automatically handle the updates coming from your Repository.
In the Todos example, they named it as [TodosOverviewSubscriptionRequested](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial?id=todosoverviewevent).

Here's the method for that event:

```dart
  Future<void> _onSubscriptionRequested(
    TodosOverviewSubscriptionRequested event,
    Emitter<TodosOverviewState> emit,
  ) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: () => TodosOverviewStatus.loading));

    await emit.forEach<List<Todo>>(
      _todosRepository.getTodos(),
      onData: (todos) => state.copyWith(
        status: () => TodosOverviewStatus.success,
        todos: () => todos,
      ),
      onError: (_, __) => state.copyWith(
        status: () => TodosOverviewStatus.failure,
      ),
    );
  }
```

This will listen to the updates coming from the exposed stream of the repository. In this way, you avoided the `bloc-to-bloc` communications and handled the logic for single-source of data properly.

Comment: Thank you @FpB for your answer. Seems to make sense and looks like a very nice solution. I will give it a try!

Comment: This solution needs me to work with the same instance of the repository over all three blocs, right? Would you pass over the context with the injected repository from screen to screen when I push a new screen over Navigator.push? It would be easier to work with a repository as a singleton, but that's not best practice, isn't it?

Comment: You can work with it as a Singleton using `RepositoryProvider`. Then access them via context.read<YourRepository> when injecting to your bloc's BlocProvider creation.

Comment: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=repositoryprovider

Comment: Great, many thanks @FpB. I've implemented the solution with the stream connecting repository and block, as well as the injection with `RepositoryProvider`. Works perfectly! You've saved my weekend :-)